# Sublime Text3 console with nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I can successfully use the node in the console of the sublime text 3 editor. I try to use nodemon to make it faster for me to run it each time I save the file.

I go tools-> build system and type this:

```
{
  "cmd": [ "/usr/local/bin/nodemon", "$file" ],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.js"
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
env: node: Argument list too long
[Finished in 25.7s with exit code 126]
[cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/nodemon', '/Users/x/Documents/MSCS/p2/v4/app.js']]
[dir: /Users/x/Documents/MSCS/p2/v4]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

And in the console here is what happens:

x$> nodemon --v app.js

env: node: Argument list too long

Thanks for help:)

Comment: well, this obviously isn't a problem with sublime, since you're getting the error from the command line as well, so I'd recommend you remove the sublimetext3 tag and all info about sublime text from your question

Comment: @Markasoftware: yeap, done

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you how I manage

1st. add the main script on the package.json to start with a simple nodemon (without args)

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node app-server.js",
...
```

2nd. tools > build system > new build system

```
{
    "shell": true,
    "cmd": ["nodemon"],
    "path": "/usr/local/bin/:$PATH",
    "env": {
            "dns_srv": "4.2.2.2",
    },
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "*.js"
}
```

still working on how to get ansi colors on the output terminal..